# Can not establish SSL-Connection

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have a server (java) and a client (android -smartphone).
I want the client to send encrypted data(GPS location, via SSL) to the server.
I want to be the only one who is able connect to my server.

For this I created:

```
serverKeyStore.jks (containing servers private key)
clientKeyStore.jks (containing clients private key)
serverTrustStore.jks (containing clients certificate exported from clientKeyStore)
clientTrustStore.jks (-||- from serverKeyStore)
```

That way the server trusts the client and the client trusts the server. (from the certificate point of view) No one else can connect to my server because the server will not trust the unknown client and will terminate the connection.

For this I did setup the server(only SSL-related part):

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\serverKeyStore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", pw);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\serverTrustStore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", pw);

ServerSocketFactory gpsServerSocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
gpsServerSocket = gpsServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(gpsSocketPort);

    while(true)
    {
    Socket newConnection = gpsServerSocket.accept();

    new NewGPSConnectionThread(newConnection).start();
    }
```

**Hoping that this is enough** an the SSLContext is now using `serverKeyStore.jks` and `serverTrustStore.jks` setted via `System-Properties`.

**The Client-Side is where I struggle:**

I added the `clientKeyStore.jks` and the `clientTrustStore.jks` to the assets-folder. I know that I can not directly refer to the file in the assets folder as the application is going to be compressed. (apk)
But I am not able to figure out how to configure the SSLSocket on the client side to use the `clientKeyStore.jks` and `clientTrustStore.jks` being able to establish a secure connection.

The ssl related part of my client-program:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
gpsSocket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(MainActivity.dstName, MainActivity.dstPortGPS);
```

But it is clear that the SSLContext or SSLSocket is not aware of my `clientKeyStore.jks` and `clientTrustStore.jks` and will not refer to default ones.

**The questions:**

**1)** Is my server ssl-configuration finished?

**2)** How can I finish my client ssl-configuration? How can I bring `client-key- and truststore` into game?